# Get-ADUser with display name as a value

Tags: powershell-3.0

**I have list of users display name in CSV file and I am trying to get samAccountName  and export it to CSV file but its not working, I understand that get-aduser doesnt accept display name as a value so I used filter but still not work help please:)

CSV file format

## User

Amer, john
Doe, John
smith, john
**

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\export.csv
foreach ($user in $list) {
Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -eq "user.user" } | Select samAccountName | Export-csv C:\export1.csv
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ForEach($user in $list{    
$dn = $user.user
Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -like $dn } | Select samAccountName > C:\export1.csv}
```

Also verify your Display names from AD match what is in CSV. But this worked for me. At first I couldn't export to C directly so I exported CSV to C:\AD\export.csv

Comment: ** CSV file have 10 names and code only execute the last display name in the list, so Export1.csv will have only one SamAccountName**

Comment: This is the finial version, thanks jdbwizzard **$list = Import-Csv C:\export.csv
foreach ($user in $list)  {  $dn = $user.user
Get-ADUser -Filter { displayName -like $dn } | select samAccountName |  Export-Csv  C:\temp\export1.csv   -NoType -Append }**

Answer (score 0):

By executing this I am getting the below error.
Get-ADUser : Variable: 'dn' found in expression: $dn is not defined.
At line:3 char:1

- Get-ADUser -filter { DisplayName -like $dn } | Select samAccountName, ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
  ```