# Find user by imported display name via powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've checked code and examples from identical questions on this site, but I'm baffled, because I'm utilizing nearly the exact same code from [Get-ADUser with display name as a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804713/get-aduser-with-display-name-as-a-value) and it just pulls empty results for me. I don't know how to continue a conversation on an existing question, so I figured I had to make my own.
Here is what I have:

```
import-module activedirectory

$csv = Get-Content users.csv
foreach ($user in $csv) {
    $user = $user.trim()
    write-host $user #A line for testing to show me what name is being analyzed
    $samName = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -like "$user*"} | select samaccountname
    write-host $samName
}

cmd /c pause | out-null
```

The output I get is:

```
John Doe

Jane Doe

Billy Ray
```

But if I change

```
    $samName = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -like "$user*"} | select samaccountname
```

to:

```
    $samName = Get-ADUser -Filter{displayName -like "John Doe*"} | select samaccountname
```

It will correctly return John Doe's samaccountname.

Comment: `-Filter "displayName -like '$user*'"`

Comment: hahaha, thank you. Now I can bang my head on the desk

Comment: An honest mistake. I expect most people are fooled by the scriptblock notation the documentation suggests for that parameter. I have no idea who at Microsoft considered this a good idea.

Comment: And apparently figure how to get it to allow searching a name with an apostrophe in it XD